# `pip: error: No command by the name pip install -r requirements.txt` after running

Tags: python, virtualenv, bootstrapping

I am trying to create a boostrap.py script that will create a virtualenv and install requirements from a requirements.txt file. Other contributors to my project should be able to checkout the project from github and run `python bootstrap.py` and then `source env/bin/activate` to have a working install of my app. Below is the script that I wrote, using this page as a guide: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

```
import virtualenv, textwrap
output = virtualenv.create_bootstrap_script(textwrap.dedent("""
def after_install(options, home_dir):
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        bin = 'Scripts'
    else:
        bin = 'bin'

    subprocess.call([join(home_dir,bin,'pip'),'install -r requirements.txt'])

"""))
print output
```

Below are the commands I am running in order to create the bootstrap and run it:

```
python create_bootstrap.py > bootstrap.py
python bootstrap.py env
```

Below is the output:

```
New python executable in env/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
Installing pip...............done.
Usage: pip COMMAND [OPTIONS]

pip: error: No command by the name pip install -r requirements.txt
  (maybe you meant "pip install install -r requirements.txt")
```

requirements.txt looks like this:

```
sqlalchemy==0.7
```

Any suggestions for a different practice or a tip on what I'm doing wrong would be helpful. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
subprocess.call([join(home_dir,bin,'pip'),'install -r requirements.txt'])
```

`'install -r requirements.txt'` is being treated as a single argument that contains spaces, so the subprocess module interprets this as a call to `pip 'install -r requirements.txt'`.

You can fix this by specifying each argument separately:

```
subprocess.call([join(home_dir,bin,'pip'), 'install', '-r', 'requirements.txt'])
```

Comment: You can use shlex.split() to split anything you would type on command line into form palatable to subprocess calls.