# Trouble installing pip (OS X 10.6 / Python 2.6.1)

Tags: macos, pip, easy-install

I'm working on a (slightly hobbled by IT policies) iMac running 10.6 Snow Leopard. I've repeatedly tried to install `pip` (as a precursor to installing `csvkit` but am confused by following error messages:

```bash
smg-02639:~ matmo$ pip install csvkit
Usage: pip COMMAND [OPTIONS]

pip: error: No command by the name pip install
  (maybe you meant "pip install csvkit")
```

That should be enough to explain why I'm aggrieved. I found a [similar, but ultimately unrelated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370215/pip-error-no-command-by-the-name-pip-install-r-requirements-txt-after-runni). *What am I doing wrong*?

For the sake of perhaps unnecessary completeness, here's the install sequence:

```bash
smg-02639:~ matmo$ sudo easy_install pip
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 1.1
Adding pip 1.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip-2.6 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
smg-02639:~ matmo$ pip help
Usage: pip COMMAND [OPTIONS]

pip: error: No command by the name pip help
  (maybe you meant "pip help")
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though I've been following outdated instructions.

I've been successful in following the [instructions here](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html)